# Examples of ActiveMQ can not be run under the Ant in the console

Tags: linux, ant, activemq-classic, opensuse

I have recently installed the ActiveMQ framework under Linux. When I want to run the examples in the map 
/opt/apache-activemq-5.15.0/examples> ant consumer 
I get the following error:

Buildfile: build.xml does not exist!
Build failed

Can anyone explain the meaning of the error? How can it be removed? Please, I insist explain step by step how I should  solve the situation because I am still a novice in ActiveMQ and Linux.

Thanks in advance

Comment: For as long as I can remember, ActiveMQ has been supplied with examples based on Maven -- old versions did use Ant, but I would be surprised if 5.15 did (I haven't looked -- the latest version I use is 5.11). The examples in later versions all have a readme.md file in each directory, that explains how to run the example. To build the examples from source you typically need to run `mvn install`, and (of course) to have Maven installed.

Comment: I've run mvn install and I've got the following error: 'Failure executing javac, but could not parse the error:
javac: directory not found: /opt/apache-activemq-5.15.0/examples/openwire/java/target/classes
Usage: javac <options> <source files>
use -help for a list of possible options' could you explain how can I fix it?

Comment: I would hazard a guess that you have used the "root" account to install ActiveMQ in the /opt directory, and now you are using a non-privileged user to build the example. But building will attempt to create the target/ directory, and you don't have access rights there. There's no particular need to use root at all here -- unpack ActiveMQ somewhere under your home directory, and build from there. If you're completely new to Linux, you've really thrown yourself in the deep end -- there's a lot of basic Linux stuff to get on top of, before you can do things like compiling code with Maven.

Comment: I unpack ActiveMQ under my username and after installation Maven (of course before install ActiveMQ) when I type `mvn -version` in console it works well, but when go to examples and I type `mvn install` I give the error. Can you give me an example how to fix it, because now I don't have enough time for study in deep I need to do my laboratory work. Thanks in advance

Comment: I'm very sorry, but I can't really add to what I said before -- this problem seems to be caused by incorrect Linux permissions. You say you installed ActiveMQ "under my username", but an unprivileged user won't normally have rights to write to /opt, so something is a bit odd. Without being there, however, I couldn't say what it is.

Comment: ok, but where I have to install ActiveMQ, in which directory I mean the best practice (your opinion) to have right privileges to run command `mvn install`?

Comment: If you don't have enough time can you give some links tutorial to solve it?

Comment: I will be very grateful for such help. Thank you in advance

Comment: Install ActiveMQ in your home directory. Or create a new user specifically to run ActiveMQ, and install in that user's home directory. This former approach is most common in dev environments, the latter in production.

Answer (score 0):

> Buildfile: build.xml does not exist! Build failed

The error message should be a big hint here, there's no build.xml

Most of the examples in the ActiveMQ source are maven based, there might be one or two in there with a build.xml you'd have to dig.  Each one generally has a README.md or the like to describe how to run the example so doing some looking around in the examples folder should be instructive.